# Помогите отсортировать массив

Tags: массивы, сортировка, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Смотрите, есть на руби массив хешей, каждый элемент хеша - это отдельный массив неупорядоченных чисел.

Нужно вернуть тот же массив хешей, но с уже с отсортированными по возростанию числами. Дано:

h = { a:[4,1], b:[6,9,3], n:[] }

Нужно получить:
h = { a:[1,4], b:[3,6,9], n[] }

Объявляется трёхдневный Конкурс, на самый короткий по длинне алгоритм!:) Победитель будет состязаться со моим решением (оно не сложное)

Второй вопрос:

я хочу файл, имя которого будет именем класса, а текст этого файла будет являться именем статического метода, а расширение этого файла будет аргументом этого метода. Короче говоря, если Дано файл:

```
String.hi
```

С текстом

```
new
```

то должно выполниться:

```
String.new('hi')
```

и на экране вывестить:

```
=> "hi"
```

Желательно уложиться в две строчки.

Удачи!!! :)))

Comment: Имя файла является существующим классом или может быть любым?

Comment: > статического метода
нет таких

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу:

```
h.each { |k,v| v.sort!}
=> {:a=>[1, 4], :b=>[3, 6, 9], :n=>[]}
```

или

```
h.each_value { |v| v.sort! }
```